# If Statement true then Redirect

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation, if-statement, ascx

Hello im learning c# at the moment and wish to If a statement is true then redirect to another ASpage so far with no luck.

My attempt is below, what the code does is check the text boxes to see if they have a value and if they do then it will save that record in the database as a new user.The code works its just the redirect at the end that isn't working.

Any help would be great

```
   protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtTitle.Text))
        {
            user.Title = txtTitle.Text;
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFirstName.Text))
        {
            user.Forename = txtFirstName.Text;
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtSurname.Text))
        {
            user.Surname = txtSurname.Text;
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtUsername.Text))
        {
            user.Username = txtUsername.Text;
        }
        // call save function at end of statements 
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtAddress.Text))
        {
            user.Address1 = txtAddress.Text;
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtAddress2.Text))
        {
            user.Address2 = txtAddress.Text;
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPostcode.Text))
        {
            user.PostCode = txtPostcode.Text;
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCode.Text))
        {
            user.CountryCode = txtCode.Text;
        }           
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEmail.Text))
        {
            user.Email = txtEmail.Text;
        }
        //if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtDate.Text))
        //{
        //    DateTime _entrydate;
        //    if (DateTime.TryParse(txtDate.Text, out _entrydate))
        //    {
        //        user.EntryDate = _entrydate;
        //    }
        //}
        user.CompanyID = AppSession.Company.ID;
        user.Status = 1;
        user.PasswordHash = "test";
        user.EntryDate = DateTime.Now;
        user.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
        user.Deleted = false;
        bool result = userDao.SaveNewUser(user);
       if (result == true)
       {
          Response.Redirect("User/List/");
       }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No error it just isnt redirecting

Answer (score 0):

You need to Redirect to another ASPX page, not a directory.

Something like

```
Response.Redirect("User/List/UserList.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private static string CheckValues(TextBox t)
{
  if(!string.IsnullOrEmpty(t.Text.Trim())
  {
      return t.Text;
  }
}

  protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            user.Title =CheckValues(txtTitle.Text);

            user.Forename = CheckValues(txtFirstName.Text);

            user.Surname = CheckValues(txtSurname.Text);

            user.Username = CheckValues(txtUsername.Text);

            user.Address1 = CheckValues(txtAddress.Text);

            user.Address2 = CheckValues(txtAddress.Text);

            user.PostCode = CheckValues(txtPostcode.Text);

            user.CountryCode = CheckValues(txtCode.Text);

            user.Email = CheckValues(txtEmail.Text);
       if(CheckValues(txtDate.Text))
        {
           DateTime _entrydate;
           if (DateTime.TryParse(txtDate.Text, out _entrydate))
            {
                user.EntryDate = _entrydate;
            }
        }
       bool result = userDao.SaveNewUser(user);
       if (result)
       {
          Response.Redirect("~/User/List/somepage"); //~ for root directory , if there is any page use that or use the exact url here.
       }
}
```

**Kindly note the above url format will only work if you have URL Rewriting/Routing in your app**

Comment: Thanks for that where would I put this code because I get expected class, delegate, enum, interface or struct error?.

Comment: you get into some mismatched braces {} some where in your code

Comment: on the Void of the class